ERROR: The preLaunch Task 'C/C++: gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1
I am using VS Code for a long time for coding and all the C++ codes I have written till now have been compiled and executed perfectly. But yesterday I faced this issue-
The error which I am facing
I tried several solutions such as deleting .vscode folder, checking for environment variables, checking C/C++ extension settings. Everything seems perfectly fine.
One thing which I noticed is whenever I am trying to run any C++ file (which worked fine before and had .exe file), the .exe file is getting deleted and no new .exe file is being made.
.exe file error
The Python files are being executed perfectly fine
The compiler has been installed correctly and everything seems perfect. I don't know how to fix this.
For reference purpose:
C/C++ extension settings
PS: I have checked other similar solutions here, and none of them has worked. And no question matched exactly to this one.
Edit: tasks.json:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}


Post the contents of your build task. It should be in the .vscode directory.

Please [edit] your question to include your tasks.json file (copy-pasted as text). If you get any text error messages in your build-log tab, then please copy-paste them as well.

I have added the tasks.json file. Kindly go through it.

I have got the solution to this issue. Thank you.

I have got the solution to this problem.
Instead of running the code using run button at the top-right corner, I used terminal to run it. The commands (in VS Code terminal) are as follows:
g++ file_name.cpp -o main

Immediately after this, enter the following command in the terminal of VS CODE:
./main

This will give the output of your code in the terminal.
After doing this, I tried clicking on Run button again, then it started working. Based on this, what I feel is, there was probably some glitch/minor issue somewhere which got fixed in this process. Maybe it was issue with my Code Runner extension.
Hope this helps.
